# Python: Can not run python file without `python` command on Mac?

Tags: python

On Terminal,

```
>> which python
/Users/Chois/.pyenv/shims/python
```

**aa.py**

```
# !/Users/Chois/.pyenv/shims python

print("a")
```

On Terminal,

```
chmod 755 aa.py
```

And execute it,

```
./aa.py
```

It occured errors

```
./aa.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"a"'
./aa.py: line 3: `print("a")'
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: You're missing a `/` between `shims` and `python` in the hashbang (having a space instead), and have an erroneous space between `#` and `!`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using full path for the python binary, your shebang line could use the `env` instruction. Then, your shebang line will end up being something like this:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 0):

The shebang line is blatantly wrong... You shouldn't have a space between the hash and the bang:

```
#!/Users/Chois/.pyenv/shims/python
```

There's also a missing slash that I filled it for you.